# How can I fix the issue where Add/Remove Software never asks for my password?

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum

Using CentOS Release 6.4 x86 when I go to **System > Administration > Add/Remove Software** and try to add software or refresh the package list, I immediately get the following error:

[image: Authorization Failed]

> **Authorization Failed**
>
> You have failed to provide correct authentication. Please check any passwords or account settings.
>
> Failed to obtain authentication

However the reason I failed to provide authentication is because *I was never asked for a password at all*. I'm running as a normal user who is a member of the `wheel` group and can run commands via `sudo`. I also can `su` to root. I am able to install software via `yum`.

How can I fix the issue where **Add/Remove Software** never asks for a password?

---

**UPDATE:** The issue appears to be with PolicyKit. Specifically, I have no authentication agent running and trying to start it results in the error

> Unable to determine the session we are in: Remote Exception invoking org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GetSessionForUnixProcess()

Some terminal output:

```
[jnet@dogYears Desktop]$ pkexec echo "test"
Error executing command as another user: No authentication agent was found.

[jnet@dogYears Desktop]$ ps awwwx|grep polkit        
 2059 ?        S      0:00 /usr/libexec/polkit-1/polkitd
28688 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep polkit

[jnet@dogYears Desktop]$ /usr/libexec/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:28725): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Unable to determine the session we are in: Remote Exception invoking org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GetSessionForUnixProcess() on /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager at name org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit: org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError: Unable to lookup session information for process '28725' org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError Unable%20to%20lookup%20session%20information%20for%20process%20%2728725%27
```

Comment: I came here with the same problem.
I am using VNC to connect into the host, no direct access (this might cause the problem)?
Anyway, since I did not find a way to make the Gnome->Software Update work, I used yum. I just saw you also suggest this. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using Gnome? Anyway, use the tools provided by whichever GUI you are using and make sure that the menu item that you use to launch your package manager points to (I believe the package manager in CentOS is called `pirut` but change accordingly):

```
gksudo pirut
```

and not just `pirut`. That should make it ask you for a password next time.

Comment: I think you're supposed to use `gksudo` instead, although I can't remember why. I'm also fairly sure you should use `pkexec`, if possible. that doesn't work with everything, though.

Comment: @strugee never heard of `pkexec` is it a Red Hat thing? As for `gksudo` on my Debian it's just a link to `gksu`.

Comment: when invoked as `gksudo` it behaves differently, like e.g. `bzip` and `bunzip`. `pkexec` is a frontend to PolicyKit; for reference, Ubuntu had just dropped `gksu` in favor of `pkexec` when I abandoned ship for Arch (just under a year ago).

Comment: Hm, I don't have `gksu` installed, so that's likely what's failing. I do have `pkexec` installed... when I run it, I get `Error executing command as another user: No authentication agent was found.`

Comment: @Josh strange, it should have come with Gnome. Do you have `gksudo`? Sounds like `pkexec` needs some configuring but I've never used it so I can't help. I assume `sudo pirut` works as expected?

Comment: @strugee as far as I know and as far as I can tell from the man page, calling `gksudo` uses `sudo` as the backend while `gksu` will use `su`. So, yes, you're right and `gksudo` is probably better. Thanks.

Comment: I have neither `gksu` nor `gksudo` and `sudo yum whatprovides "*/gksu"` returns no matching packages. Weird. Yes I am using Gnome...

Comment: @Josh some pointers [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/7185/no-gksudo-so-just-su-or-sudo-then/).

Answer (score 0):

I found that this too was happening to me so I reconnected my Raspberry Pi via the HDMI to my TV and found that it now worked, and the error message was gone. I only got the error message when using Remote Desktop Connection to connect to my PI. The only two things I had installed are xrdp and samba.